# simple SQL query with select and order options doesn't work

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, phpactiverecord

I am using php activerecord and codeigniter for my project and it usually works perfect when i use

```
Table::find('all')
```

But when i want to select specific columns in the database i always get a "Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ActiveRecord\DatabaseException' with message '42000, 1064, ...(etc)...". Basically it says that my SQL is wrong.

This is the code i use (from the phpactiverecord wiki)

```
$data = Table::find('all', array(
    'select' => 'somecolumn', 
    'order'  => 'someothercolumn asc'
));
```

This is what the wiki says:

```
# fetch all books, but only the id and title columns
Book::find('all', array('select' => 'id, title'));
# sql => SELECT id, title FROM `books`
```

Comment: That is strange. You'd be probably best of by starting to debug some. I would inspect the whole error first (maybe even show it here?) and you can check the last run query from the connection, see what it actually send to your database (look it up, but phpactiverecord has a function to get the last query)

Comment: I worked around this by just using find(all) and ordering with the arrays i get out of it, but when i have time i will post the errors and sql query here.

Comment: I have never faced this issue but I suggest you to update your activerecord library to latest version and see if you see this error.